# use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'

Tags: objective-c, theos

I'm using theos to build my tweak. And this happened: **Tweak.x:18:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'**

Here's my code

```
#import "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSTask.h"
%hook SBStatusBarManager
UITextField *textField;
- (void)handleStatusBarTapWithEvent:(id)arg1
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                            message:@"message"
                                            delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
  textField.placeholder = @"123";
  [alert show];
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInterger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex == 1)
  {
    UITextField *command = alert.textField;
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = @"/bin/bash"; 
    task.arguments = @[command];
    [task launch];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init]
    initWithTitle:@"123"
    message:nil delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"123" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  }
}
}
%end
```

Please help, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The closing brace for `handleStatusBarTapWithEvent` is in the wrong place. You’ve got  `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`  defined *inside* `handleStatusBarTapWithEvent`, which is not correct, and the compiler is confused by that. Move the closing brace for `handleStatusBarTapWithEvent` before  `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

Comment: But I need to use "alert" inside alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex, but I definite it in handleStatusBarTapWithEvent, how to solve that?

Comment: No offense, but, no, you don’t need/want an Objective-C method inside another. That’s simply not valid syntax in Objectice-C, hence the compiler error.

Comment: @FangziONG - The `clickedButtonAtIndex` is a delegate method. So it needs to be a full-fledged instance method of that delegate object (i.e. of `self`).